# Streamed HTML files have no Open option in IE

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, filestream

We have some kind of file explorer in our ASP.NET web application.

It can stream files of various types that reside on an external towards the user.
Now everything is working fine, but now they want to stream HTML files and they give issues.

When I want to stream a HTML file in IE, the download prompt does not give me the option to open it, it only has the Save and Save As options.

I've been googling for days, but the only thing I could find is how to turn off the Open button, but I want it to be there while it isn't by default.
Both Firefox and Chrome do have an Open option in their download prompts.

The code on the external server to stream the files is as followed:

Note: file is an instance of our own file object that contains info, like path, filename, flags,... about the file we ant to stream

```
        System.IO.FileInfo fileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo("C:\\\\MyFolder\\" + file.FullName);
        if (fileInfo.Exists)
        {
            System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream("C:\\\\MyFolder\\" + file.FullName, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);

            string filename = file.Name.Replace(" ", "_");

            page.Trace.IsEnabled = false;                
            page.Response.Expires = 0;
            page.Response.Buffer = true;
            page.Response.Clear();
            page.Response.ContentType = MimeTypeParser.GetMimeType(fileInfo.FullName); //Gets the Correct content type: "text/html" in this case
            page.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fs.Length.ToString());
            page.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
            int bufferSize = 8192;
            // default to 4K, may want to use 8K instead           
            byte[] bytes = null;
            bytes = new byte[bufferSize + 1];
            int read = 0;

            //Helper to read the bytes to the response steamer
            while ((InlineAssignHelper(read, fs.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length))) != 0)
            {
                page.Response.OutputStream.Write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
            page.Response.OutputStream.Flush();
            //close off response or else you get corrupted files
            fs.Close();
            page.Response.End();
        }
        else
        {
            page.Response.StatusCode = 404;
            page.Response.End();
        }
```

On the application itself the following code is used to get the data from the streamer and push it to the response to the client:

```
public void StreamFile(int id, System.Web.HttpRequest clientRequest, System.Web.HttpResponse clientResponse)
        {
            try
            {
                OurDomain.File file = OurBLL.FileService.GetFile(id);
                if (file != null)
                {
                    string url = "http://FilestreamingServer?StreamFile.aspxid=" + file.Pkey + "&userName=" + userName;
                    Uri uri = new Uri(url);
                    System.Net.WebRequest request = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);

                    request.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
                    System.Net.WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();// 1st code block on the other server is invoked here

                    clientResponse.ContentType = response.Headers["Content-Type"];
                    clientResponse.AddHeader("Content-Length", response.Headers["Content-Length"]);
                    clientResponse.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", response.Headers["Content-Disposition"]);
                    int bufferSize = 8192;
                    // default to 4K, may want to use 8K instead           
                    byte[] bytes = null;
                    bytes = new byte[bufferSize + 1];
                    System.IO.Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
                    int read = 0;
                    while ((InlineAssignHelper(read, stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length))) != 0)
                    {
                        clientResponse.OutputStream.Write(bytes, 0, read);
                    }
                    clientResponse.OutputStream.Flush();
                    OurBLL.LogService.WriteDownloadLog(file);
                    //close off response or else you get corrupted files
                    clientResponse.End();
                }
            }
            catch (System.Threading.ThreadAbortException ex)
            {
                //is due to response.end call.
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Log exception
            }
        }
```

When I look at the response in F12, I see the expected headers in the response:

- Response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK Pragma: no-cache
- Content-Type: text/html
- Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
- Refresh: 3580
- Content-Disposition:    attachment; filename=Test.html
- X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
- Date: Wed, 11 Dec 2013 11:19:19 GMT
- Content-Length: 222

As far as I know everything is there to show a regular download prompt with all options.

What am I missing?

Is there a header tag to force the prompt to turn on the Open option, like you have "X-Download-Options: noopen" to turn it off?

I know you can open the file in the browser by adding "inline" in the Content-Disposition header instead of attachment, but that's no option cause that'll open the page in the current window and I have to keep the file browse open.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. This is what i  discovered:

- If you choose another "Default program" than Internet explorer to open html  files you will get the "Open" option.

Note: This only applies to html files. If you, for example, download pdf files and the default program to open pdf is set to internet explorer, you will still get the "open" option.

Anyone a better solution?